# Replace non-unicode string with unicode in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have imported a dataset into my postgres database. It contains a few rows where a unicode character wasn't properly imported and they show like 'u00e9' so records with words like 'Café' look like 'Cafu00e9'.

I now want to create a trigger to replace 'u00e9' with the proper unicode character. This can be done like so:

```
SELECT replace('Cafu00e9', 'u00e9', U&'\00e9');
---- Result ---
Café
```

However, I don't want to have to list all unicode characters in a big chain of `replace` calls. So I tried using regex:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Cafu00e9', 'u(00[a-z0-9]{2})', U&'\\\1');
```

This raises an error though:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  invalid Unicode escape value at or near "\1'"
LINE 1: ...CT regexp_replace('Cafu00e9', 'u(00[a-z0-9]{2})', U&'\\\1');
```

Which is due to the `U&` before the replacement_string. This works for getting the string as I like it:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Cafu00e9', 'u(00[a-z0-9]{2})', '\\\1');
----- Result ----
Caf\00e9
```

But adding `U&` causes the above error. It seems like Postgres is evaluating `U&'\\\1'` without taking regex into regard at all.

What would be a nice way to solve this without having to list all characters?

Comment: Right, regex is good for *text*, *string* manipulation, to eval the result, you should use something different.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any suggestion?